# Condition for firebase database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to set up Firebase database rules so that it will require authentication to read/write for a specific node only and open for all other nodes. I tried this but didn't work. Any idea?

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        “TESTNODE”: {
             ".read": "auth != null”,
             ".write”: "auth != null”
        }
    }
}
```

my structure is like this:

```
"WORKINGNODE1":....
"WORKINGNODE2":....
"WORKINGNODE3":....
"WORKINGNODE4":....
"TESTNODE":....
```

Comment: Pretty sure rules cascade down so having read true, write true as the first statements override everything below then. Move those two statements to the end

Comment: sorry move those two to the end still makes TESTNODE public to read/write